# Fulfilling conditions of Inverse function(?)

Tags: inverse-function, constraints, inverse-function-theorem

Let's assume that

$$h(g(t))=t$$

What conditions ae needed to say that

$$g(h(t))=t$$

Is satisfied too?

(Provided that $h$ and $g$ are continuous and derivatable, but not knowing whether they have inverse though..)

I am not sure about the title of this question. If you know better title, feel free to let me know or edit this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the domain is $\mathbb R$ then  a necessary and sufficient condition is that $h$ is one-to-one.  If $h$ is one-to-one change $t$ to $h(t) $ in the hypothesis to get $h(g(h(t))=h(t)$. This implies $g(h(t))=t$ because $h$ is one-to-one. Conversely the equation $g(h(t))=t$ clearly implies that $h$ is one-to-one.

Comment: So easist but loose condition to check is checking if $h'(t)$ does not change its sign, right?

Comment: Why use derivatives at all? You can ask this question about functions that are not even continuous and the answer is always the same.

Comment: You don't need the assumption that the domain is $\mathbb{R}$, either: it's true whenever the domain of $g$ is the codomian of $h$, and the domain of $h$ is the codomain of $g$ (otherwise one of the compositions is undefined), and your proof works unchanged.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you for your clarification.(I agree with you(and your proof). The comment was specific only for a function that is analytic but not being able to think its graph at the first glance(in my current curriculum)  :) Anyway thanks for your help!

Comment: @user3482749 Oh thank you.

Comment: Something is clearly wrong here, though it's not immediately clear what. If $g$ is not surjective, then $gh$ cannot be the identity (since it cannot be a bijection). The hypothesis gives that $g$ is injective and $h$ surjective, and the conclusion requires that $g$ is surjective and $h$ injective. This turns out to be a necessary and sufficient condition.